# Fill in color for transparent area in 3D plot

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, geometry, lattices

I have a lattice of large spheres:

```
vecs = Entity["Lattice", "BodyCenteredCubic"]["MinimalVectors"];
bcc = Append[vecs, {0, 0, 0}];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.6], Ball[#, Sqrt[3]/2] & /@ bcc}]
```

[image: lattice of spheres]

I would like to fill in the transparent space between the spheres with some semi-transparent color instead of it simply being empty space between the spheres. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you say what color fills up this space right now?

Comment: I would simply say it's transparent?

Comment: Maybe https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268421/how-can-i-generate-a-swiss-cheese-type-region-and-render-it-transparent/268423#268423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may choose a transparent background color with a low opacity like:

```
vecs = Entity["Lattice", "BodyCenteredCubic"]["MinimalVectors"];
bcc = Append[vecs, {0, 0, 0}];
Graphics3D[{{Green, Opacity[0.1], Cube[3.8]}, {Opacity[.6], 
   Ball[#, Sqrt[3]/2] & /@ bcc}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]